# How to find an estimate for the point of inflection of array of numbers? (Python)

Tags: python, derivative

Let's say i have an array of numbers. If i sort the array i have a decently smoothed curve. Is there an easy way to get an estimate for the point where the slope of the line increases the most? (I think this is called point of inlection.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a sample array? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Correction: `point of inflection` or `inflection point` is the point where gradient changes sign, not where it changes the most.

Comment: Can you symbolically calculate the derivative of the line? I think you just want to find the maximum of the function's second derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a digital signal, the derivative correlates to the difference between two adjacent values.

So to get that, if `a` is a numpy array:

```
a_prime = a[1:] - a[:-1]
```

What you're looking for is the point at which the derivative of the derivative is the greatest (which isn't the inflection point):

```
answer = np.argmax(a_prime[1:] - a_prime[:-1])
```